# PORT=8080 was written in .env file sowhywe write const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080 in server.js ,how is process.env.PORT value different from 8080

Tags: node.js, mern

PORT=8080 was written in .env file so why we write const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080 in server.js ,how is process.env.PORT value different from 8080

can we only write PORT = process.env.PORT in server.js instead of  const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080 in server.js?

Comment: The `|| 8080` is optional and only in place in case the environment variable is unset

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why use process.env.PORT in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61285092/why-use-process-env-port-in-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic way of providing a default value to a variable in JS.

The `||` operator takes two arguments. If the first argument is evaluated as "truthy", the operator returns the first argument.

```
let x = true || 'hello'    //true
```

If the first argument is evaluated "falsy", the second argument is evaluated and returned the results.

```
let x = undefined || 'hello'   //hello
```

The same principle is applied in your case. If the `env.PORT` is set, it will return the value. If not it will return `8080`.

Answer (score -1):

You can write only var PORT = process.env.PORT. The || we use for deployment purpose and to run in local env. If any port is defined in .env file it will run on that port otherwise it will run on port that we have defined after ||.